# Is there a proper way to have a config or settings module in angular? (or is that a no-no)

Tags: angularjs

Being that I use PHP a lot I frequently come across settings/configs in php apps. For example wordpress's wp-config, or drupal's settings.php.

What's the best practice for making a global config in angular1 that would be easily accessible. I'm using requirejs so I would just put it into a folder or similar. Is this a bad practice? In my mind all it would be is just a big settings object and I would change values there and call them later.

Comment: What i usually do - all application 'fixed' params i include them in the code. All 'changeable' params I load them from an external file (simular as the php.ini files) - user specific settings (logged in user settings) load them through API from DataBase. But be aware about sensitive settings, don't store / handle them client side.

Comment: One suggestion is go through some of multitude of seed apps and see how they use config files. Can install in short time with various package managers or scaffolding tools like yoeman and play with them

Comment: So what i'm seeing is I would use constants? Does that sound right?